Why is Console.readPassword() inserting a line?
I am creating a password manager, and I am using Console.readPassword() to enter passwords without it displaying on the screen. However, I have noticed some interesting behavior of this method. Whenever I run the following program in my Powershell, a line is inserted between the prompt and the printout afterwards.
I found another post stating that Console.readPassword() should not do this, so I double checked my code and made a simple example and still found the same behavior. I also tried running the same exact code in a different environment, namely the Intellij terminal, and I found that it behaved differently. The Powershell still insists on adding a line, but the Intellij terminal does not, and I do not know why. The code I ran along with the outputs are below. For both examples, I typed abcd as the password and hit enter.
Scratch.java
import java.io.Console;

public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Console console = System.console();
        char[] password = console.readPassword("Enter password: ");
        System.out.println("new line");
    }
}

Output when java Scratch is run in Powershell:
Enter password:

new line

Output when java Scratch is run from the terminal in Intellij:
Enter password:
new line

I don't see why the same code should behave differently. Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Can you please give an example password too?

@g00se I added an example password I entered into the post. Thanks!

maybe because PowerShell does interpret "\r\n" as two line feeds instead of one (as usual for Windows) [one more reason to not run Java on PS :-/ ]

@user85421 On PS, I just ran System.out.println("hello\r\nbye"); and I didn't get an extra newline between hello and bye. I got the same behavior on Intellij terminal.

No problem here either

@user85421 what makes you think that?

tested it on Windows 10, OpenJDK 23, unable to reproduce it: screenshot

@user85421 that is very interesting. I am using jdk 17, so I wonder if that has anything to do it.

JDK17: screenshot (using a simple password like 123)

Wow that's surprising. I wonder why my system is performing the way it is. Thank you for your comments. They've been very interesting to compare with.
